# next js run dev Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, npm, next.js

I wanted to learn Next Js and followed [Youtube Video Next.js Crash Course - Server Side React by Traversy Media](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkOVe40Sy0U)

I also followed the setps from [Nextjs Offical Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs)

I have just put below code in pages/index.js file

```
export default function Home()
{
    return <h1>Welcome to my Website</h1>
}
```

In Package.json I have put below code :

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start"
},
```

I run below cmd to run the next app

```
npm run dev
```

When I open my Chrome Browser I see Nothing rendered and in console I am getting below error.

> `VM117:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>       at eval (platform.js?2a2e:14)
>       at Object../node_modules/ally.js/util/platform.js (main.js?ts=1592604315070:1786)
>       at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1592604315070:863)
>       at fn (webpack.js?ts=1592604315070:151)
>       at eval (detect-focus.js?93d2:19)
>       at Object../node_modules/ally.js/supports/detect-focus.js (main.js?ts=1592604315070:1102)
>       at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1592604315070:863)
>       at fn (webpack.js?ts=1592604315070:151)
>       at eval (supports.js?750b:21)`

Is there any other setting I need to do to start next app ?

Answer (score -3):

I suggest this `"scripts":...` should be put to the particular place inside pre-filled `Package.json`, not replacing the whole file

Comment: Apart from being quite a vague answer, it's not even coherent with the question